# I need help proving a statement about rational roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have no idea where to start...this is the statement:

> If a polynomial of degree not greater than 5 with rational coefficients has multiple roots, it has also a rational root, except in the case when the degree is 4 and the polynomial is a perfect square.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like the statement is false?  Take $x^2 + 1.$  It has rational coefficients, degree no greater than $5$, and has multiple roots, but none rational ($\pm i$).  It's neither degree $4$ nor a perfect square.

Comment: But it doesn't have multiple roots, one is $i$ and the other $-i$

Comment: Ahh, OK.  "Has multiple roots" means "has roots with multiplicity greater than one," not "has more than one root."  That's where I was confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outline:** Suppose the polynomial $P(x)$ is irreducible over the rationals. Then there are no multiple roots. For if $\alpha$ is a multiple root of $P(x)$, then $\alpha$ is a root of $P'(x)$, and hence of $\gcd(P(x),P'(x))$. Thus the gcd $D(x)$   divides $P(x)$.

If the degree of $P(x)$ is $\le 3$, reducibility forces a rational root. The only way we could fail to have a rational root is if $P(x)$ is a product of two irreducible quadratics, or the product of an irreducible quadratic and an irreducible cubic.

If $P(x)$ is the product of two irreducible quadratics, each with roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then $P(x)$ is **almost** a perfect square. (The problem has a mistake: $2(x^2+1)^2$ and $-(x^2+1)^2$ are not perfect squares. But $P(x)$ must be a constant times a perfect square.)

Finally, we show that irreducible quadratic and irreducible cubic is impossible. For let $\alpha$   be a root of the irreducible quadratic. Then since $\alpha$ is a root of the cubic, it is a root of their gcd. Thus the quadratic divides the cubic.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I have left out a smallish amount of detail.